# Nautilus not showing default folder icons in side bar. (Side Panel)

Tags: 20.04, gnome, nautilus, icons

Usually, nautilus shows pictures, downloads and other similar folders on the sidebar, **In my case after some of the boots nautilus does not show default icons in the sidebar.**

These icons are so much helpful for me. e.g. *Downloads, Pictures, Videos*

### My current nautilus:

[image]

### System info

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64
- Kernel: 5.13.0-28-generic
- Shell: zsh 5.8
- DE: GNOME
- CPU: Intel i3-3110M (4) @ 2.400GHz
- Memory: 1626MiB / 7804MiB

### What I tried before asking this question

- removed `~/.config/nautilus` folder but nothing happened
- reinstalled nautilus using `sudo apt purge nautilus && sudo autoremove && sudo apt install nautilus` - this also not worked!
- also tried rebooting after making every step.

Thank You, for reading my question. **Please help me to get back my icons in the side panel.**

Comment: Dear,  @Someone I want icons in the panel, not in bookmarks. also, favourites option not available in ubuntu.